# How can Environment.StackTrace throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException?

Tags: c#, .net

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx), `Environment.StackTrace` can throw [`ArgumentOutOfRangeException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception(v=vs.110).aspx) but I don't understand how this is possible.

Environment.cs `StackTrace` ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/bc146608854d1db9cdbcc0b08029a87754e12b49/src/mscorlib/src/System/Environment.cs#L1206))

```
public static String StackTrace {
    [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]
    get {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<String>() != null);

        new EnvironmentPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted).Demand();
        return GetStackTrace(null, true);
    }
}
```

Calls `GetStackTrace(Exception, bool)` where `Exception` is null.

Environment.cs `GetStackTrace(Exception, bool)` ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/bc146608854d1db9cdbcc0b08029a87754e12b49/src/mscorlib/src/System/Environment.cs#L1219)) (comments removed, they are irrelevant)

```
internal static String GetStackTrace(Exception e, bool needFileInfo)
{
    StackTrace st;
    if (e == null)
        st = new StackTrace(needFileInfo);
    else
        st = new StackTrace(e, needFileInfo);

    return st.ToString( System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.TraceFormat.Normal );
}
```

The above method has the potential to call two constructors of `StackTrace`, `StackTrace(bool)` and `StackTrace(Exception, bool)`.

We know from the first call that if this method is reached via the `Environment.StackTrace` call then `StackTrace(bool)` is guaranteed to be called.

But `StackTrace(bool)` doesn't throw any exceptions according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6zh7csxz(v=vs.110).aspx). The other possible constructor call, `StackTrace(Exception, bool)` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsay49kt(v=vs.110).aspx)) does throw an exception, but it's `ArgumentNullException` not `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.  I don't see any other method calls made in the code that would throw `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

So what am I missing? Is it actually possible for `Environment.StackTrace` to throw an exception and if so how?

Comment: I know `new StackTrace(int)` can do that, but not sure how it would propagate to `Environment.StackTrace`. Perhaps these are shown from some automated tool. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybch8k4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @leppie I noticed that too, the methods using `skipFrames` were the only places in `Stacktrace.cs` that would throw `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, but as far as I could see the calls made directly from `Environment.StackTrace` don't hit any of the methods that use the `skipFrames` parameter.

Comment: Exception info in MSDN articles is general unreliable.  It is always incomplete and does suffer from copy/paste bugs.  Hard to get those articles fixed, if nobody ever encountered the exception then nobody ever thinks to *remove* a documented exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retrieving the property value in fact shouldn't throw an exception. We've removed the exception information from the documentation for the [Environment.StackTrace property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library(d=lightweight)/z72zz8f7(l=en-us,v=VS.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Reading the source code I agree that ArgumentOutOfRangeException should never be thrown on the code path from Environment.StackTrace.

It wouldn't be the first time MSDN needed a correction. You should click the "Any suggestions?" link in the upper-right. After answering "Was the page helpful? yes/no", they will prompt for any other feedback.